# Rails: find with constraints on polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Two models:

```
User has_one :location, as: locatable
Location belongs_to :locatable, polymorphic: true
```

So far so good. Now say I want to find a User with a certain name and city:

```
User.joins(:location).where(name: 'Eddie Explosion', location: { city: 'Kaboom' })
```

...but when I run that, boom,

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "location".

Any idea what's going on here / how to fix this? Can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really experiment on the exact case you have, but I have done something similar to what you want to do in my application, here is an example below:

```
User.joins(:locations).where("users.name = 'Eddie Explosion' AND locations.city = 'Kaboom'")
```

Cheers   :))

Comment: That worked, thank you. It came down to using 'locations' rather than 'location'. In case it helps anyone in the future, you can also do this: User.joins(:location).where(name: 'Eddie Explosion', locations: { city: 'Kaboom' })